# Image won't adjust to fill width of container on right side only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The image won't adjust to fill the right side of the container. There is a white space on the right side only. Here is my code.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
     <img src="../images/Hero-1.png" alt="Hero-1" width="1170" height="601"class="img-responsive1"></div>
   </div>
 </div> 


.img-responsive1 {
    col: col-lg-12 col-md-12;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -21px;
}
```

Comment: You could add [tag:twitter-bootstrap], to invite more responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove negative margins from your image and paddings from your columns.

Also, you don't need to specify the width of image in your img tag because you are specifying it in css to 100%.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <img src="../images/Hero-1.png" alt="Hero-1" height="601" class="img-responsive1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 


.img-responsive1 {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-lg-12, .col-md-12 {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly to fill the container horizontally. I have removed the negative margins. However, the top margin I had at -21px is not filling the top of the container now. Again, thank you very much for the correction and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with all of those negative margins (bad practice), but if you want the image to fill 100% of the width of the container, you can do this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.img-responsive1 {
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is 12 columns grid. Every class(grid) must have margin 0.